# Strange image object behaviour in IE. Is my solution the best one?

Tags: javascript

I have a function which receives **either** a preloaded **JS image object** or an **image url**.  This is passed in as the `photo` variable.

I perform a check to see whether the 'photo' var is a string or not.  If it is I create a new image object and use the onload event to fire the generateSlide() function passing in the newly created image object as seen below:

```
renderSlide: function (slideindex, photo, external, count, text) {
        var self = this;
        var image = new Image();
        if (typeof (photo) == 'string') {
            image.onload = function () {
                self.generateSlide(slideindex, image, external, count, text);
            };
            image.src = photo;
        } else {
            image.src = photo.src;
            self.generateSlide(slideindex, image, external, count, text);
        }
 },
```

If the 'photo' var is a preloaded JS image object I simply run the function itself passing the image object into generateSlide();

Everything works great however for some reason in IE 9 I cannot simply pass through the 'photo' var directly into the generateSlide() function.  I have to create a new image object and set the src to match the photo object's src attribute.

This makes no sense to me and I can't understand why this would be?

In the cases where the photo var is an actual JS image object it is confirmed as loaded elsewhere. ( I am preloading assets );

In summary, the code above works fine but can anyone explain **WHY** I have to create a new image object and cannot simple pass in the original one? Is there a more elegant solution?  So far I haven't noticed any problems with the above method but is anyone aware of any pitfalls using this approach.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it sounds like it might be a scope issue, do you have the full source code for this? Did you try assigning photo to image then passing image through?

Comment: Yes I have the full source but it's part of such a big project it would be difficult to post to be honest.  I'll try as you suggest.  Thanks Gareth.

Comment: That doesn't work i'm afraid.  Would a scoping issue not effect all browsers???

Comment: I would have thought so too. I can't think of anything else which would cause this though. What error does IE 9 give?

Comment: Does something like this help? (function(photo){ self.generateSlide(slideindex, photo, external, count, text); })(photo);

Comment: Yep! Putting it in a closure did the trick... And I've just realised why... I'm running many of these asynchronously (well semi-asynchronously since JS is single threaded) so the photo variable is not always guaranteed to be the correct one.  Putting it into a closure as you suggest works perfectly.  Thanks! I'm surprised you managed to diagnose the problem since I hadn't mentioned the way in which this function what being called.  Well done! If you want to rewrite it as an answer I will mark it correct. Cheers Gareth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like an issue with scope. Have you tried putting the call in a closure to make sure the correct photo is captured?

```
renderSlide: function (slideindex, photo, external, count, text) {
        var self = this;

        if (typeof (photo) == 'string') {
           var image = new Image();
            image.onload = function () {
                self.generateSlide(slideindex, image, external, count, text);
            };
            image.src = photo;
        } else {
          (function(photo){
            self.generateSlide(slideindex, photo, external, count, text);
          })(photo);
        }
```

},